# Entity framework code first one-to-one two way navigation

Tags: entity-framework, one-to-one

In every single place I've searched so far, all one-to-one relationships in entity framework have a principal and a dependent entity. What I want is a one-to-one relationship between two principal entities.

So lets setup an example. Imagine car engines and cars. A car engine can exist without a car, and a car can exist without a car engine. A car engine *may* be placed in a car (optionally) and a car *may* have a car engine placed in it (optionally). I want to be able to `LoadAsync` the associated car when I have a car engine (if available) and the associated car engine when I have a car (if available).

As you can see, I can't implement this using a principal and a dependent entity.

The entities should look something like this:

```
public class Car
{
    [Key]
    public string SN { get; set; }
    public string Plate { get; set; }

    public string IncludedEngineId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("IncludedEngineId")]
    public virtual Engine IncludedEngine { get; set; }
}

public class Engine
{
    [Key]
    public string SN { get; set; }
    public int CC { get; set; }

    public string PlacedInCarId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("PlacedInCarId")]
    public virtual Car PlacedInCar { get; set; }
}
```

If I do that however, car C1 could have IncludedEngineId E1, but E1 could be PlacedInCarId C2! That doesn't create a "pairing" between C1 and E1.

Is there a way to implement this using annotations? If not, is there a way using fluent api? Or do I have to implement this as business logic?

Comment: By saying "car engine" you already know that engine is dependent to car :)

Comment: A car engine can be sold separately from a car, can be used for decoration, or can be removed from a car and be placed in another car, or go to some factory to get repaired. It is a principal entity, that happens to optionally pair with a single car.

Comment: Ah I see clearly now. Maybe a join table let name it EquipmentRelation which contain each piece of equipment: Car 1---* EquipmentRelation  * ---- 1 Engine.

Comment: That crossed my mind as well. The EquipmentRelation could have a compound key that consists of the two foreign keys, and set each foreign key as unique, and that seems to solve all problems. I was thinking of a simpler solution. Maybe some kind of annotations that instructed entity framework to do the join table for me. If that is not the case, your solution is the next best thing. You should post it as an answer.

Comment: EF will generate the join table when building the model (under certain conditions) but it is always better to be explicit.  By the fact that you have a 1:0 relationship established (string keys are nullable, so 1 to zero or 1) you shouldn't get duplicate pairings unless I missed something.  You really shouldn't use user input as primary keys, there should always be a surrogate primary key.

Comment: If you try to use the code I provided, you get a runtime error that EF is not able to guess which one is the principal entity. So, no join table generated. Also, I have a 0..1:0..1 relationship. Or maybe two 1:0..1 relationships. Finally, there is nothing in my question suggesting that the keys are user input. Take not that pairings (C1, E1) and (C2, E1) I mention in the question are not duplicate, but is also not acceptable to coexist in the join table - the one that is not generated.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this is a kind of circular reference between two table and hope EF does not support this feature.. either you have to create seprate table for both or do coding for this get work.

Comment: It would be a circular reference problem if the relationships were not optional. It would be a principal-dependent entity problem if one of them was not optional. Neither of these applies in my case.